# Taskbar Button Group Failure w/ File Explorer

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

As long as I can recall, Win10 Taskbar button for File Explorer fails to group folders several times a day. I use Thumbnail & Icon Cache Rebuilder to delete the thumbnail cache and the Explorer folders group properly for a time. But then randomly, as near as I can tell, stop grouping at some point and I need to delete cache again. Rinse, repeat ad nauseam.

So, is there a more permanent fix? I've done some searching and have not found a viable solution. Sigh.

Thanks for reading and/or helping!

Hope you and yours are well and safe!

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Asking again...anyone have any ideas?